# Overriding Angular Material body typography

Tags: angular, material-design, angular-material

I've created a custom theme using Angular Material (v 5.2.4) in an Angular (v 5.2.0) app.

my-theme.scss:

```
@import '~@angular/material/theming';

@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=IBM+Plex+Sans+Condensed:300,400,500');

@include mat-core();

$my-theme-primary: mat-palette($mat-deep-orange);
$my-theme-accent:  mat-palette($mat-amber, A200, A100, A400);
$my-theme:   mat-light-theme($my-theme-primary, $my-theme-accent);
$my-typography: mat-typography-config(
  $font-family: '"IBM Plex Sans Condensed"'
);

.my-theme {
  @include angular-material-theme($my-theme);
  @include angular-material-typography($my-typography);
}
```

I've also added the class names `mat-app-background mat-typography` to the `body` in the index.html page for my app.

When I add the `my-theme` class to the container of my app (inside the `body`), then all of the material components **do** get the custom font (for things like radio button labels, etc), but nothing outside of a component gets it.

I've also tried using the `angular-material-typography()` and `mat-base-typography()` mixins to no avail.

How can I override the fonts from the `mat-typography` class?

Comment: [offical docs](https://material.angular.io/guide/theming) and [this article](https://medium.com/@tomastrajan/the-complete-guide-to-angular-material-themes-4d165a9d24d1) explain themes in detail too

Comment: Neither of those places explains typography

Comment: They do say how to get what you want with less code... ill post an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The accepted question pointed me in the right direction, this is how I ended up getting it working, for future reference:

```
@import '~@angular/material/theming';

@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=IBM+Plex+Sans+Condensed:300,400,500');

@include mat-core();

$my-theme-primary: mat-palette($mat-deep-orange);
$my-theme-accent:  mat-palette($mat-amber, A200, A100, A400);
$my-theme:   mat-light-theme($my-theme-primary, $my-theme-accent);
$my-typography: mat-typography-config(
  $font-family: '"IBM Plex Sans Condensed"'
);

.my-theme {
  @include angular-material-theme($my-theme);

  // this is what fixed it
  .mat-typography & {
    font-size: mat-font-size($my-typography, body-1);
    font-family: mat-font-family($my-typography, body-1);
    line-height: mat-line-height($my-typography, body-1);

    h1, h2, h3 {
      font-family: mat-font-family($my-typography, body-1);
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 12):

```
    @import '~@angular/material/theming';
    @import './color_palette.scss'; // contains custom palette
    @import './app_theme.scss'; // contains app mixin

   $app-typography: mat-typography-config(
      $font-family: 'Muli, Roboto, "Helvetica Neue", sans-serif',
      $display-4:     mat-typography-level(112px, 112px, 300),
      $display-3:     mat-typography-level(56px, 56px, 400),
      $display-2:     mat-typography-level(45px, 48px, 400),
      $display-1:     mat-typography-level(34px, 40px, 400),
      $headline:      mat-typography-level(24px, 32px, 400),
      $title:         mat-typography-level(20px, 32px, 500),
      $subheading-2:  mat-typography-level(16px, 28px, 400),
      $subheading-1:  mat-typography-level(15px, 24px, 400),
      $body-2:        mat-typography-level(14px, 24px, 500),
      $body-1:        mat-typography-level(14px, 20px, 400),
      $caption:       mat-typography-level(12px, 20px, 400),
      $button:        mat-typography-level(14px, 14px, 500),
        // Line-height must be unit-less fraction of the font-size.
      $input:         mat-typography-level(16px, 1.25, 400)
    );

    @include mat-core($app-typography);

    $primary: mat-palette($deeppurple); // $deeppurple form color_palette
    $accent:  mat-palette($blue);  // $blue form color_palette
    $warn:    mat-palette($red);  // $red form color_palette
    $theme:   mat-light-theme($primary, $accent, $warn);
    @include  app-theme($theme);  //app mixin from app_theme

    body, html {
      margin: 0;
      height: 100%;
      font-size: mat-font-size($app-typography, body-1);
      font-family: mat-font-family($app-typography);
      line-height: mat-line-height($app-typography, body-1);
    }
```

Comment: Thanks, this was super useful!

Answer (score 4):

This alone (taken from @Dharan G's answer) will get the font into all components:

```
$config: mat-typography-config(
  $font-family: 'IBM Plex Sans Condensed, sans-serif'
);

@include mat-core($config);
```

Answer (score 2):

If you have mat-typograph in you index.html file you need to remove it to override the mat config.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like this is an old one, but the accepted answer did not solve it for me.

Even though the font specified in `mat-typography` was applied when the DOM element was inspected, visually it still was displaying the text in the wrong font.

I managed to get it to work by having angular apply the font class like this:

```
.font-fix {
  font-family: '<custom-font>';
}
```

```
<div [class.font-fix]="true">Text displayed correctly!</div>
```